# Automated cross stich pattern

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to create a cross stitch pattern with python as shown in the attached image.

So far I simply have the pixilated image. I could import it in excel and  manually add the grid and colors etc. But how can I 'easily' automate this in python? Can I use any of the normal figure plotting functions (pyplot), or should I look into tkinter?

I'm fairly ok making scripts in python for engineering purposes, but completely new to GUI-stuff.

Ideally my output would be a vectored pdf

[image: Cross stitch pattern]

```
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

arr = misc.imread('Fox_drawing_pixelized.png', mode= 'RGBA') # 640x480x3 array

fig = plt.figure()
imgplot = plt.imshow(arr) # RGBA
ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b', linestyle='-')
plt.minorticks_on()
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-',linewidth=.3)
fig.savefig("foo.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

- How do I set the gridlines at 0.5 rather than on the units (in the middle through each pixel)?
- How do I plot text throught each pixel, I already have the image in an array with numbers how to plot this on top?

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Matplotlib can create grids, it can draw text or other symbols, it can colorize image arrays, it can export pdf. So this should be straight-forward. (I don't understand what this has to do with GUI if the output should be pdf.) If you have a problem, show a  [mcve] of the issue (not complete animal), and clearly state at which point you are stuck.

Comment: To start with, you can open your image with `PIL`, then use `numpy.asarray(image)` to convert it in an array that you can display with `pyplot.imshow`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. I had the img plotted, but was not sure for the lettering if Matplotlib is the way to go. I had seen some sudoku examples using tkinter, so thought maybe that would be a good basis to start from.

Comment: BTW: you can use Python to open/create excel file and add elements in cells, so you can still do it with excel. Python has also modules to create PDF - ie. PyPDF - so you can create PDF directly.

Comment: To change the gridlines position, you can change the ticks with `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, width + 1, 1))`. This will put the major grid lines on the half integers. If you want to configure the minor ticks, just add `minor=True` in `ax.set_xticks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To shift the gridlines, you can simply change the ticks position:
  `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, arr.shape[1], 5))`
  will put one major tick each 5 pixels starting from the border of the first pixel.
  `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, arr.shape[1], 1), minor=True)`
  does the same thing but every pixel for minor ticks. And then do the same for y but with `arr.shape[0]`.
- To add text, you can simply use `ax.text(x, y, 'text')`. I used a dictionary to match the colors (in hex format because rgb lists cannot be dictionary keys) to the texts. What you need to pay attention to is that (i, j) matrix indexes correspond to (y, x) coordinates.

Here is the full code:

```
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex

arr = misc.imread('image.png', mode= 'RGB') # array
# adapt figure size to the image size.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(0.2*arr.shape[1], 0.2*arr.shape[0]))
imgplot = plt.imshow(arr) # RGB
ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b', linestyle='-')
plt.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-',linewidth=.3)

# put a major gridline every 5 pixels
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, arr.shape[1], 5))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.5, arr.shape[0], 5))
# set ticks label
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0, arr.shape[1], 5))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(0, arr.shape[0], 5))
# put a minor gridline every pixel
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, arr.shape[1], 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.5, arr.shape[0], 1), minor=True)
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)  # reduce space around image

# display text
colors_to_text = {'#000000': 'B', '#ffffff': 'W', '#f58a35': 'O', '#bcbbbb': 'G'}

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        # get the text corresponding to the pixel color
        txt = colors_to_text.get(to_hex(arr[i,j]/255), '')
        # display text (x, y are inverted compared to the i, j indexes of the matrix)
        ax.text(j, i, txt, color='#888888', horizontalalignment='center', 
                verticalalignment='center', fontsize=7)

fig.savefig("foo.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

The image [image: pixelated image] gave me this result:
[image: result]

Comment: @user1908460 I think it is correlated to the size of the figure vs the size of the image. If the pixel size is too small on the figure, then the rendering is not good even in pdf. Try to make the fig size adapt to the image size (I have updated the answer)